# Move up cache bar from down to header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to move up the `cache bar` at the webpage: http://www.skandicinkasso.de/ -  cant move the `element` because it is at the `bottom` of the "`DOM`"

I have been trying remove that positioning, and put the element inline where i wanted it, but i cant do that way.

i want to move the bar to here: http://prntscr.com/fsqb5d

Comment: Add some code you have tried?

Comment: been tried position: absolute;

Answer (score 0):

Change your ginger_container.bottom css to

```
.ginger_container.bottom {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 125px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

remove bottom: 0 and add top: 125px; width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that enough?

```
    .ginger_container.bottom {
      border-top: 1px solid #cccccc !important;
      top: 125px;
      height: 28px;           
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the CSS** : From `.ginger_container.bottom` remove `position:fixed;` and all other position attributes(left,right,bottom).

[image]

**In the HTML** : Move the entire `<div class="ginger_banner-wrapper">` and its contents into the `header` and palce it just above the closing header tag `</header>`.

[image]

**Output**: Its fixed and stays close below the navigation bar.

[image]